# Overlay Image on Playing Video at a Specific Time/Frame

Tags: android, image, video, overlay, android-canvas

I have this VideoView overlayed with another view for a canvas used for drawing by freehand or draw series of images from file. I want to show the images/drawings on a specific time/frame on the video. I've already set up a thread that would check the elapsed time of the video where I would show the images but my problem is that during playback everything freezes except for the video which continues playing. Only the last image is shown after the video has finished.

Here is my layout:

```
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/flVidArea"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1" >

        <com.sample.CustomVideoView
            android:id="@+id/vvBg"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center" />

        <com.sample.DrawingView
            android:id="@+id/drawing"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="330dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:background="@null"
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </FrameLayout>
```

Here is my CustomVideoView (Implemented own videoView to listen for play/pause event)

```
public class CustomVideoView extends SurfaceView implements MediaPlayerControl {
private String TAG = "VideoView";
private Uri mUri;
private int mDuration;

private SurfaceHolder mSurfaceHolder = null;
private MediaPlayer mMediaPlayer = null;
private boolean mIsPrepared;
private int mVideoWidth;
private int mVideoHeight;
private int mSurfaceWidth;
private int mSurfaceHeight;
private MediaController mMediaController;
private OnCompletionListener mOnCompletionListener;
private MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mOnPreparedListener;
private int mCurrentBufferPercentage;
private OnErrorListener mOnErrorListener;
private boolean mStartWhenPrepared;
private int mSeekWhenPrepared;

private PlayPauseListener mListener;

public CustomVideoView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    initVideoView();
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    this(context, attrs, 0);
    initVideoView();
}

public CustomVideoView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    initVideoView();
}

@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int width = getDefaultSize(mVideoWidth, widthMeasureSpec);
    int height = getDefaultSize(mVideoHeight, heightMeasureSpec);
    if (mVideoWidth > 0 && mVideoHeight > 0) {
        if (mVideoWidth * height > width * mVideoHeight) {
            height = width * mVideoHeight / mVideoWidth;
        } else if (mVideoWidth * height < width * mVideoHeight) {
            width = height * mVideoWidth / mVideoHeight;
        } else {
        }
    }
    setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
}

public int resolveAdjustedSize(int desiredSize, int measureSpec) {
    int result = desiredSize;
    int specMode = MeasureSpec.getMode(measureSpec);
    int specSize = MeasureSpec.getSize(measureSpec);

    switch (specMode) {
    case MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED:

        result = desiredSize;
        break;

    case MeasureSpec.AT_MOST:

        result = Math.min(desiredSize, specSize);
        break;

    case MeasureSpec.EXACTLY:
        result = specSize;
        break;
    }
    return result;
}

private void initVideoView() {
    mVideoWidth = 0;
    mVideoHeight = 0;
    getHolder().addCallback(mSHCallback);
    getHolder().setType(SurfaceHolder.SURFACE_TYPE_PUSH_BUFFERS);
    setFocusable(true);
    setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
    requestFocus();
}

public void setVideoPath(String path) {
    setVideoURI(Uri.parse(path));
}

public void setVideoURI(Uri uri) {
    mUri = uri;
    mStartWhenPrepared = false;
    mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
    openVideo();
    requestLayout();
    invalidate();
}

public void stopPlayback() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.stop();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
}

private void openVideo() {
    if (mUri == null || mSurfaceHolder == null) {
        return;
    }
    Intent i = new Intent("com.android.music.musicservicecommand");
    i.putExtra("command", "pause");
    getContext().sendBroadcast(i);

    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        mMediaPlayer.reset();
        mMediaPlayer.release();
        mMediaPlayer = null;
    }
    try {
        mMediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer();
        mMediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(mPreparedListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnVideoSizeChangedListener(mSizeChangedListener);
        mIsPrepared = false;
        Log.v(TAG, "reset duration to -1 in openVideo");
        mDuration = -1;
        mMediaPlayer.setOnCompletionListener(mCompletionListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnErrorListener(mErrorListener);
        mMediaPlayer.setOnBufferingUpdateListener(mBufferingUpdateListener);
        mCurrentBufferPercentage = 0;
        mMediaPlayer.setDataSource(getContext(), mUri);
        mMediaPlayer.setDisplay(mSurfaceHolder);
        mMediaPlayer.setAudioStreamType(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);
        mMediaPlayer.setScreenOnWhilePlaying(true);
        mMediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
        attachMediaController();
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
        return;
    } catch (IllegalArgumentException ex) {
        Log.w(TAG, "Unable to open content: " + mUri, ex);
        return;
    }
}

public void setMediaController(MediaController controller) {
    if (mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController.hide();
    }
    mMediaController = controller;
    attachMediaController();
}

private void attachMediaController() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaController != null) {
        mMediaController.setMediaPlayer(this);
        View anchorView = this.getParent() instanceof View ? (View) this
                .getParent() : this;
        mMediaController.setAnchorView(anchorView);
        mMediaController.setEnabled(mIsPrepared);
    }
}

MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener mSizeChangedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnVideoSizeChangedListener() {
    public void onVideoSizeChanged(MediaPlayer mp, int width, int height) {
        mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
        if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {
            getHolder().setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
        }
    }
};

MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener mPreparedListener = new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
    public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
        mIsPrepared = true;
        if (mOnPreparedListener != null) {
            mOnPreparedListener.onPrepared(mMediaPlayer);
        }
        if (mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.setEnabled(true);
        }
        mVideoWidth = mp.getVideoWidth();
        mVideoHeight = mp.getVideoHeight();
        if (mVideoWidth != 0 && mVideoHeight != 0) {

            getHolder().setFixedSize(mVideoWidth, mVideoHeight);
            if (mSurfaceWidth == mVideoWidth
                    && mSurfaceHeight == mVideoHeight) {
                if (mSeekWhenPrepared != 0) {
                    mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mSeekWhenPrepared);
                    mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
                }
                if (mStartWhenPrepared) {
                    mMediaPlayer.start();
                    mStartWhenPrepared = false;
                    if (mMediaController != null) {
                        mMediaController.show();
                    }
                } else if (!isPlaying()
                        && (mSeekWhenPrepared != 0 || getCurrentPosition() > 0)) {
                    if (mMediaController != null) {
                        mMediaController.show(0);
                    }
                }
            }
        } else {
            if (mSeekWhenPrepared != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mSeekWhenPrepared);
                mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
            }
            if (mStartWhenPrepared) {
                mMediaPlayer.start();
                mStartWhenPrepared = false;
            }
        }
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener mCompletionListener = new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
    public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
        if (mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.hide();
        }
        if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
            mOnCompletionListener.onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
        }
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener mErrorListener = new MediaPlayer.OnErrorListener() {
    public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int framework_err, int impl_err) {
        if (mMediaController != null) {
            mMediaController.hide();
        }

        if (mOnErrorListener != null) {
            if (mOnErrorListener.onError(mMediaPlayer, framework_err,
                    impl_err)) {
                return true;
            }
        }

        if (getWindowToken() != null) {
            Resources r = getContext().getResources();
            int messageId;

            if (framework_err == MediaPlayer.MEDIA_ERROR_NOT_VALID_FOR_PROGRESSIVE_PLAYBACK) {
                messageId = android.R.string.VideoView_error_text_invalid_progressive_playback;
            } else {
                messageId = android.R.string.VideoView_error_text_unknown;
            }

            new AlertDialog.Builder(getContext())
                    .setTitle(android.R.string.VideoView_error_title)
                    .setMessage(messageId)
                    .setPositiveButton(
                            android.R.string.VideoView_error_button,
                            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                        int whichButton) {

                                    if (mOnCompletionListener != null) {
                                        mOnCompletionListener
                                                .onCompletion(mMediaPlayer);
                                    }
                                }
                            }).setCancelable(false).show();
        }
        return true;
    }
};

private MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener mBufferingUpdateListener = new MediaPlayer.OnBufferingUpdateListener() {
    public void onBufferingUpdate(MediaPlayer mp, int percent) {
        mCurrentBufferPercentage = percent;
    }
};

public void setOnPreparedListener(MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener l) {
    mOnPreparedListener = l;
}

public void setOnCompletionListener(OnCompletionListener l) {
    mOnCompletionListener = l;
}

public void setOnErrorListener(OnErrorListener l) {
    mOnErrorListener = l;
}

SurfaceHolder.Callback mSHCallback = new SurfaceHolder.Callback() {
    public void surfaceChanged(SurfaceHolder holder, int format, int w,
            int h) {
        mSurfaceWidth = w;
        mSurfaceHeight = h;
        if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared && mVideoWidth == w
                && mVideoHeight == h) {
            if (mSeekWhenPrepared != 0) {
                mMediaPlayer.seekTo(mSeekWhenPrepared);
                mSeekWhenPrepared = 0;
            }
            mMediaPlayer.start();
            if (mMediaController != null) {
                mMediaController.show();
            }
        }
    }

    public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = holder;
        openVideo();
    }

    public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder) {
        mSurfaceHolder = null;
        if (mMediaController != null)
            mMediaController.hide();
        if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
            mMediaPlayer.reset();
            mMediaPlayer.release();
            mMediaPlayer = null;
        }
    }
};

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mIsPrepared && mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaController != null) {
        toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onTrackballEvent(MotionEvent ev) {
    if (mIsPrepared && mMediaPlayer != null && mMediaController != null) {
        toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
    }
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (mIsPrepared && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK
            && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP
            && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN
            && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MENU
            && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_CALL
            && keyCode != KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENDCALL && mMediaPlayer != null
            && mMediaController != null) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_HEADSETHOOK
                || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY_PAUSE) {
            if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
                pause();
                mMediaController.show();
            } else {
                start();
                mMediaController.hide();
            }
            return true;
        } else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_STOP
                && mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            pause();
            mMediaController.show();
        } else {
            toggleMediaControlsVisiblity();
        }
    }

    return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
}

private void toggleMediaControlsVisiblity() {
    if (mMediaController.isShowing()) {
        mMediaController.hide();
    } else {
        mMediaController.show();
    }
}

public void start() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        mMediaPlayer.start();
        mStartWhenPrepared = false;
    } else {
        mStartWhenPrepared = true;
    }

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPlay();
    }
}

public void pause() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        if (mMediaPlayer.isPlaying()) {
            mMediaPlayer.pause();
        }
    }
    mStartWhenPrepared = false;

    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onPause();
    }
}

public int getDuration() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        if (mDuration > 0) {
            return mDuration;
        }
        mDuration = mMediaPlayer.getDuration();
        return mDuration;
    }
    mDuration = -1;
    return mDuration;
}

public int getCurrentPosition() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        return mMediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
    }
    return 0;
}

public void seekTo(int msec) {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        mMediaPlayer.seekTo(msec);
    } else {
        mSeekWhenPrepared = msec;
    }
}

public boolean isPlaying() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null && mIsPrepared) {
        return mMediaPlayer.isPlaying();
    }

    return false;

}

public int getBufferPercentage() {
    if (mMediaPlayer != null) {
        return mCurrentBufferPercentage;
    }
    return 0;
}

@Override
public boolean canPause() {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekBackward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean canSeekForward() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public int getAudioSessionId() {
    return 0;
}

public void setPlayPauseListener(PlayPauseListener listener) {
    mListener = listener;
}

interface PlayPauseListener {
    void onPlay();

    void onPause();
}
}
```

This is the Drawing View (Canvas) for drawing images/freehand drawing

```
public class DrawingView extends View {

Queue<DrawAgain> qDa;
DrawAgain drawAgain;
private Path drawPath;
private Paint drawPaint, canvasPaint;
private int paintColor = 0xFF660000;
private Canvas drawCanvas;
private Bitmap canvasBitmap;
private float brushSize, lastBrushSize;
private boolean erase = false;

public DrawingView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    setupDrawing();
}

private void setupDrawing() {

    brushSize = getResources().getInteger(R.integer.small_size);
    lastBrushSize = brushSize;
    drawPath = new Path();
    drawPaint = new Paint();
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
    drawPaint.setAntiAlias(true);
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
    drawPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    drawPaint.setStrokeJoin(Paint.Join.ROUND);
    drawPaint.setStrokeCap(Paint.Cap.ROUND);
    canvasPaint = new Paint(Paint.DITHER_FLAG);
}

@Override
protected void onSizeChanged(int w, int h, int oldw, int oldh) {
    super.onSizeChanged(w, h, oldw, oldh);
    canvasBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    drawCanvas = new Canvas(canvasBitmap);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    canvas.drawBitmap(canvasBitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);
    canvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
    float touchX = event.getX();
    float touchY = event.getY();

    switch (event.getAction()) {
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
        drawPath.moveTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        break;
    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
        drawPath.lineTo(touchX, touchY);
        drawCanvas.drawPath(drawPath, drawPaint);
        drawPath.reset();
        break;
    default:
        return false;
    }

    drawAgain = new DrawAgain(touchX, touchY, event, drawPath, drawCanvas,
            drawPaint);

    invalidate();
    return true;
}

public void setColor(String newColor) {
    invalidate();
    paintColor = Color.parseColor(newColor);
    drawPaint.setColor(paintColor);
}

public void setBrushSize(float newSize) {
    float pixelAmount = TypedValue.applyDimension(
            TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, newSize, getResources()
                    .getDisplayMetrics());
    brushSize = pixelAmount;
    drawPaint.setStrokeWidth(brushSize);
}

public void setLastBrushSize(float lastSize) {
    lastBrushSize = lastSize;
}

public float getLastBrushSize() {
    return lastBrushSize;
}

public void setErase(boolean isErase) {
    erase = isErase;
    if (erase)
        drawPaint
                .setXfermode(new PorterDuffXfermode(PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR));
    else
        drawPaint.setXfermode(null);
}

public void startNew() {
    drawCanvas.drawColor(0, PorterDuff.Mode.CLEAR);
    invalidate();
}

public void drawBitmap(String filePath) {
    File imageFile = new File(filePath);
    if (imageFile.exists()) {

        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(filePath);
        drawCanvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, canvasPaint);

        invalidate();
    }
}
}
```

This is the main activity. The process here is that during 3, 9, 13 and 17 sec of video, an image shows.
On AsyncTask, I placed drawImages() on postExecute because it's not permitted to do View processes on another thread.

```
public class OverlayActivity extends Activity {

MediaMetadataRetriever mt;
private FrameLayout flAreaCopy;
private String source;
private CustomVideoView video;
private DrawingView drawView;
Bitmap drawingPic = null;

private String[] imagesName = new String[] { "image_9335.png",
        "image_3680.png", "image_13427.png", "image_17684.png" };
MediaController mediaController;
long videoDuration;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(false);
    actionBar.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);
    actionBar.setTitle("Back");
    actionBar.setDisplayUseLogoEnabled(false);

    source = "/mnt/sdcard/sample4.mp4";

    setContentView(R.layout.videoeditor_layout);

    flAreaCopy = (FrameLayout) this.findViewById(R.id.flVidArea);
    flAreaCopy.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    video = (CustomVideoView) this.findViewById(R.id.vvBg);
    video.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
    mediaController = new MediaController(this) {
        @Override
        public void hide() {
            this.show(0);
        }

    };
    mediaController.setMediaPlayer(video);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(video);
    video.setMediaController(mediaController);
    video.setVideoURI(Uri.parse("file://" + source));
    video.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mediaController.show(0);
            new DrawTask().execute();
        }

    });

    video.setPlayPauseListener(new CustomVideoView.PlayPauseListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPlay() {
            Log.i("OverlayAct", "Play!");
            videoDuration = video.getDuration();
            new DrawTask().execute();
        }

        @Override
        public void onPause() {
            Log.i("OverlayAct", "Pause!");
        }
    });

}

private void drawImages() {

    while (video.isPlaying()) {
        int time = video.getCurrentPosition() / 1000;

        if (time == 3) {
            drawView.drawBitmap(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Kobera/" + imagesName[0]);

        } else if (time == 9) {
            drawView.drawBitmap(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Kobera/" + imagesName[1]);

        } else if (time == 13) {
            drawView.drawBitmap(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Kobera/" + imagesName[2]);

        } else if (time == 17) {
            drawView.drawBitmap(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                    + "/Kobera/" + imagesName[3]);
        }
    }
}

private class DrawTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean> {

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        super.onPreExecute();

    }

    @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {

        return true;

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Boolean isValid) {

        drawImages();

        super.onPostExecute(isValid);
    }
}

}
```

Here is the screenshot of my app:

[image]

My problems are:

1. When showing a series of images on specific time of the video, it only works after the video has finished playing (but when i put logs on where the images should be shown, it shows that the phone is working on the process of showing the images).
   I think maybe its because of the thread I'm using but I can't think of a better approach to do this.
2. Also when the video is playing everything freezes. The drawing buttons and MediaController won't work anymore.

I hope somebody can help me with this. Thanks.

Comment: did you find any solution ?